# How to store data on a "dynamic buffer" in Qt?

Tags: qt, io-buffering

I tried **QBuffer** but it seems that it's not useful for me. I need something like the [Buffer class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html) in Java

Namely, I want to inject data in buffer and when I read n-size of data (from the end), this should be removed or the seek pointer should be moved in the correct position.

Context: I must send a file (line by line) through serial port. The main program injects the file and my thread which manage the connection, sends the data from buffer when is possible.

Comment: check out [QByteArray](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbytearray.html)

Comment: And how I use it for my purpose?

Comment: Guess I could use **append** and **remove** methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [QBuffer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbuffer.html) with a [QDataStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html) class.

So, the QBuffer provides a QIODevice over a byte array and the QDataStream then gives the serialization functionality that you desire.

Comment: Use the stream operators << and >> for reading and writing. If the buffer doesn't delete the data, you possibly could derive from QBuffer and call QByteArray::remove for the read functions. Alternatively, use a QLocalSocket for transmitting from one thread to the other. This provides the stream functionality you asked for.